# how to remove the banner in EDK2 Front Page

Tags: bios

I am having problem removing the banners in EDK2 Front Page.   It looks like there are about 5 lines reserved for banners  even though it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Change the GUID of the front page form set.   There are banners reserved for the default Front Page GUID in EDK2.